# SSRS Subscription returning different values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, subscription

When I run my report manually I get the expected values however when I run this report via a subscription the values are different. I have worked out that the data being returned is a sum of the filtered data and the filtered data + 1 (e.g 15-07-2015 - 16-07-2015 23:59:59). The filter is using the below code to work out yesterdays weekday last year.

```
    Function DateYesterdayLastYearFrom() As Date
    Return customDate.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1)
End Function

Function DateYesterdayLastYearTo() As Date
    Return (customDate.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1) + new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59))
End Function
```

Is there any way that the subscription is messing with the date filter upon generation or have I missed something in my code?

Comment: I would think is something to do with different date formats on your local machine/server?

Comment: Did change the code to pass in a static date (dd-mm-yyyy format) and it worked as intended.